# Write Map in File with Consumer in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, consumer

I want to write a class `MapWriter<T>` that Implements a Consumer of `Map<T,Integer>` that writes the input map into a text file. I have a final attribute outputFilePathStr.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MapWriter<T> implements Consumer<Map<T,Integer>>{

    private final String outputFilePathStr;

    @Override
    public void accept(Map<T, Integer> tIntegerMap) {
        Files.write(outputFilePathStr, tIntegerMap);
    }
}
```

I have an error in Files.write(outputFilePathStr, tIntegerMap), i can't compile it.

[image]
P.S: The annotation `@AllArgsConstructor`
is from Lombok plugin, it generates automatically all the constructors.

Comment: “I have an error”…don’t overwhelm us with so much information.

Comment: There is no overload of method `Files.write` which accepts `java.util.Map` as a parameter: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: thank you for all your answers. I add a picture which there is the error and the imports.

Comment: @nkrivenko so what is the solutions ? i have to convert it ?

Comment: Take a look at available methods in Files responsible for writing data. For instance https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.charset.Charset,java.nio.file.OpenOption...) looks promising. You just need to convert map to String so you could use it as `CharSequence csq` parameter.

Comment: Also what do you want to do if file already exists and contains some data? Do you want to append new data at the end of the file (as a new line) or erase old data and replace it with new one.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, errors, etc.  Copy/paste the information, correctly formatted, into your question.

Comment: @Pshemo erase old data and replace it.

Comment: I didn't found a solution so anyone can help me ?

Comment: The error message does already say it. There is no `Files.write` method with a `String` and `Map` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it. i changed this:

```
 Files.write(outputFilePathStr, tIntegerMap.toString().getBytes())
```